# Private QT signal

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a data model that I want other objects to be able to watch for updates, but I don't want to give anyone control of the update signal itself. I've come up with a something that makes sense to me conceptually, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm wondering if anyone could explain why I will never get it to work, or if i'm missing something that could make this work. Effectively I have a Client class (QObject) that has an arbitrary slot and Model class that has a private signal.

important Client class code (public SLOT):

```
void client::doUpdate()
{
  std::cout << "HELLO UPDATE" <<std::endl;
}
```

Model code:

```
void Model::unRegisterForUpdates(const char* qt_slot_handle, QObject* o)
{
  QObject::disconnect (this, SIGNAL( updateHandles() ),
                       o,  qt_slot_handle);
}

void Model::registerForUpdates(const char* qt_slot_handle, QObject* o)
{
  QObject::connect( this, SIGNAL( updateHandles() )
                    , o, qt_slot_handle
                    , Qt::UniqueConnection);  
}
```

Main func:

```
Model foo;
client * cl  = new client();
client * cl2 = new client();
std::cout << SLOT(cl->doUpdate())  << std::endl;
std::cout << SLOT(cl2->doUpdate()) << std::endl;
foo.registerForUpdates( SLOT(cl->doUpdate())  , cl);
foo.registerForUpdates( SLOT(cl2->doUpdate()) , cl2);
```

Output:

```
1cl->doUpdate()
1cl2->doUpdate()
Object::connect: No such slot client::cl->doUpdate() in .../main.cpp:14
Object::connect: No such slot client::cl2->doUpdate() in .../main.cpp:15
```

It will probably come down to the amount of introspection I can get into the signal/slot system.I'm not sure how to interpret the connect error message. It tells me that connect is concerned with the static information for the class Client, but the slot string indicates the specific instance name - I'm wondering if by the time I get to Model::connectHandle() this name loses its meaning.

Comment: Strictly speaking, private signals are impossible because Qt meta call system does not respect scopes on the one side, and because `signals` is define for `protected` on another.

Comment: by "but I don't want to give anyone control of the update signal itself" I assume you mean you don't want to expose the address of the object that generates the signal?

Comment: @Jay My intention is to keep the Model strictly responsible for sending change notifications. The code base I'm working in could be described as signal/slot storm and I feel that preventing the call model->updateHandles() will help force us to be more intentional with signals/slots.

Comment: @Lol4t0 - Of course there are ways of getting at the signal, but someone will have to stop and think about it first - which is good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple case of typo:

In class, you have `doUpdate()` slot.

In main func, you're passing `onUpdate()` to `SLOT()` macro.

Also, you shouldn't include the instance in the `SLOT()` macro, just the slot name (and parameters). Exactly the same syntax you'd use in `connect()`. Qt's signal-slot connection mechanism is based on string comparison. In other words, your main should do this:

```
foo.registerForUpdates(SLOT(doUpdate()), cl);
foo.registerForUpdates(SLOT(doUpdate()), cl2);
```

Comment: Thank you, that is working. It's amazing what a typo can mask.

Comment: Note that Qt 5 has a new syntax for `connect()` that allows for compile time checking unline the old method which relies on runtime wiring up based on string names: http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: ... and that syntax (`&Sender::valueChanged`) fully respects C++ access rules, since it is just a pointer to member function.